# How can I get a list of files on my computer that are not "owned" by any package?

Tags: apt, deb

I'm contemplating writing a script that does this:

- Goes through each file in /usr/lib
- Does a `dpkg -s` search on each file.
- Reports a list of "orphan" files not belonging to any .deb package.

The idea is that over time, I've installed a lot of `make install` software and I'd like to get a list of leftover files from manually installed software I've since deleted.

Comment: In the future, make sure everything you install outside the packaging system gets installed to /usr/local or /opt. Then you'll have a clear separation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
find /usr/lib -type f -exec dpkg -S {} + 2>&1 >/dev/null | sed -r 's/^[^/]+//'
```

I'll warn you now: it's slow.

Comment: It's faster: `find /usr/lib -type f -exec dpkg -S {} + | grep 'no path found'`

Comment: No disagreement there. 2012's Oli wasn't as good as 2015's. I've updated it so it only returns a list of files.

Answer (score 4):

You can run the following command

```
join -t '' -v1 <(find /usr/lib | sort) \
               <(grep -h /usr/lib /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | sort -u)
```

that compare the list of files in `/usr/lib` with the list of files present in at least a file in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/<NAME>.list` (the files used by `dpkg -S`). The `-v1` option would report files present in the first list but not in the second one.

On my machine this difference list gives more than 5000 hits, so I doubt it could be of any help.

Comment: Works really fast for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo aptitude install cruft
man cruft
sudo addgroup cruft
sudo chmod g+rwx /var/spool/cruft
sudo chown root:cruft /var/spool/cruft
sudo addgroup $USER cruft
cruft -r cruftreport
sudo chown root:root /var/spool/cruft
less cruftreport
```

Comment: I like the `man cruft` in there, but a tiny bit more explanation on cruft and why you recommend it would be nice!  :P  ;-)

Comment: This will not work, more precise: (1) "chown: missing operand after ‘root:cruft’". Need to write: "sudo chown root:cruft /var/spool/cruft" instead (2) "sudo addgroup $USER cruft" will require closing/opening new shell (relogin). (3) Calling cruft will require "sudo cruft" if you want to inspect all dirs.